# Writing a SQL query involving aggregate functions

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have created a the following view in my Database after combining multiple tables. A `select * from MYViEW` gives the following result below.

```
ProductID | TechID | ContactID | Priority | FIRSTNAME | MIDDLEINI | LASTNAME | 
1123         2406       1371        1        Pradeep       X          Nayak      
1123         2406       1368        2        Hello         W          World      
1123         2406       1363        3        Foo           Y          World    
1299         2279       1208        2        Some          Z          Dude
```

And I need the OUTPUT result to below to be displayed:

```
ProductID | TechID | ContactID | Priority | FIRSTNAME | MIDDLEINI | LASTNAME | Buyers                                        |
1123         2406       1371        1        Pradeep    X           Nayak      Nayak, Pradeep X; World, Hello W; World, Foo Y  
1299       2279         1208        2        Some       Z           Dude       Dude, Some Z
```

For every Product ID and Tech ID have a single record, and all the Buyers must be combined in a column in the format `LastName, FirstName MiddleIni` and each name separated by a space. I have already tried to use the custom aggregate function from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131056.aspx) for combing the results to a single column. Please let me know if you can help me with a query for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will display the data in the manner than you want:

```
select t1.ProductID,
  TechId,
  x.ContactID,
  x.Priority,
  FirstName,
  MiddleIni,
  LastName,
  stuff((select  '; ' + lastname + ', ' + FIRSTNAME + ' ' + MIDDLEINI
          from yourtable t2
          where t2.productid = t1.productid
        FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') 
from yourtable t1
inner join
(
  select min(priority) priority, ProductID, max(ContactID) ContactID
  from yourtable
  group by ProductID
) x
  on t1.ProductID = x.ProductID
  and t1.contactid = x.contactid
```

## see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b1064/2)

This is getting the `MIN()` priority value - the highest - and then the `MAX()` contactId

Comment: This is really a wonderful solution. I was trying to come up with a solution for this since a day or two. Thanks for the illustration with SQL Fiddle and introducing to XML PATH. I highly appreciate your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so this is a good question and the best answer I've ever seen is [here](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/). I am going to recommend you use the `XML PATH` option for your needs and it would look something like this:

```
SELECT v.ProductID, v.TechID, v.ContactID, MIN(v.Priority) AS Priority,
    STUFF ( ( SELECT '; ' + bv.LastName + ', ' bv.FirstName + ' ' + bv.MiddleIni
              FROM [MYVIEW] bv
              WHERE bv.ProductID = v.ProductID AND
                    bv.TechID = v.TechID AND
                    bv.ContactID = v.ContactID
              ORDER BY bv.LastName, bv.FirstName, bv.MiddleIni
              FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '') AS Buyers
FROM [MYVIEW] v
GROUP BY v.ProductID, v.TechID, v.ContactID
```

Comment: Thanks for recommending XML PATH. I thought this was a difficult question and posted here. I don't really understand on why this is downvoted :(

Comment: @Pradeep: no problem. I'm not sure why it was down voted either but they should have been man enough to leave a comment. I've never understood how you can be so cowardly that you can't even support your decision online. You don't even have to face the person.

Answer (score -3):

Would something like this provide the output you're looking for?

```
SELECT LASTNAME + ', ' + FIRSTNAME + ' ' + MIDDLEINI
, ProductID
, TechID
, ContactID
. Priority
FROM MYVIEW
GROUP BY LASTNAME + ', ' + FIRSTNAME + ' ' + MIDDLEINI
, ProductID
, TechID
, ContactID
. Priority
```

Comment: No this does not combine multiple buyers of the same ProductID into a single column. See the required output.